# Where to find the config-file for ProFTP?

Tags: ftp

I just installed proftpd and I was wondering where I could find the configuration file, so I can set-up the server according to my wishes. I have tried /etc/proftpd.conf and /usr/local/etc/proftpd.conf, which both result (via "sudo gedit (path's from above)") in an empty document?

Answer (score 3):

Try `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf` - see the [Ubuntu Community documentation on ProFTPD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ProFTPD).

Comment: Ah, that worked for me! I tried to log in with "username" and "password" of my Ubuntu account, that doesn't work though, could you give me some information about that, please?

Comment: The easiest way to configure proftpd` is to use the GUI application `gadmin-proftpd`. It allows for configuring users, too.

Comment: @Johann: system users should be able to log into proftpd by default, without any additional config. If it doesn't work, we need more info to debug this. Did you try to access from localhost or from a remote system? What do the proftpd logs tell? What does the ftp client tell? Any errors?

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I was going crazy with my configuration file not even being read, everything I found online said it needed to be at `/etc/proftpd.conf` but your path is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Some more things that should be checked in cases like this:

1. The right access permissions have been assigned to the folders in the server.
2. The file could also be /etc/proftpd.conf.

You can check the syntax of the config file with the command

```
sudo proftpd -td5
```